# is it possible to cut text from string like this?

Tags: android

I want to put extra value from intent to other intent. But in other intent, app get all value. Example:

```
mAddress.setText(" from " + address);

String put_address = mAddress.getText().toString();

editIntent.putExtra("put_address", put_address);
```

is it possible to cut text "from" and get only address variable ???

Comment: just use split and get substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, you can use jagapathi's answer. In his example he uses regular expression.
Regular expressions can help to parse, find, cut substrings using a particular pattern. In his code he splits string by any space character.

But, imho, the simplest solution is to create a substring using this code:

'put_address.substring(7);'

Comment: understood :)) tks u

Answer (score 3):

you can split a string like

```
str = "From address@dd.com";
 String modified = str.replace;
```

now `splitstr` contain your split strings

> splitStr[1] contains "address@dd.com"

Can also use

```
str.substring(str.indexOf(" ")+1);
```

Comment: regular expression for space (only works if words are divided with space)

Comment: is that i don't understand your idea or you misunderstand my idea? =))

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: I just need get address value to other intent, not include "from"... if you understand, can you edit my example ?? sr for my bad english.

Comment: I hardly get you can you explain more

Comment: I you want to remove "from". From "from jagg@g.com". My code works

Comment: I understand.. tks u bro

Answer (score 0):

use one of these solutions:

1. String input = put_address.trim().substring(5);

*** note: 5 is index of real address first character;

2. String input = put_address..split(" ")[1];